# Converting signal to NSException only work the first time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, signals, segmentation-fault

It seems that when BSD signals are converted to thrown exceptions, it only work the first time but not subsequent times.

I tried to convert signals to exception via the following call I made in the main method just before calling `NSApplicationMain` :

```
[[NSExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler] setExceptionHandlingMask:NSHandleUncaughtSystemExceptionMask];
```

This does work the first time a `signal` occurred.  But the second time it happens, the thread just hangs but still allowing other threads to run.  Is there any way I can make this happen each time?

Btw, I tested this by having a button that triggers a `SIGSEGV` violation by writing to address zero:

```
char* p = NULL;
*p = 'x';
```

What I want is for that to throw an exception every time -- just like Java's `NullPointerException`.  But currently it only works the first time it is executed, subsequently the thread hangs.